# IllegalStateException (Unknown Source) when using iter.remove() in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am getting an illegalStateException error when trying to remove an element from an ArrayList in the follow code. I have googled and found that this error usually happens when you don't have a iter.next() in the code but I am pretty sure mine is set up correctly.

```
for (Iterator<String[]> x = PAuditjobslist.iterator(); x.hasNext(); ){

    String[] temp = x.next();

    if(temp.length > 2){

        String PAdate = dateFudger(temp[PAuditDate],f);
        int docCounter = 0;

        for(String[] y: cancelledjobslist){

            String Cndate = y[canJobDate];

            if(temp[PAuditName].equals(y[canJobName]) && PAdate.equals(Cndate) && 
                    documentNameList.get(docCounter).equals(temp[PAuditDocName]) ){

                x.remove();


            }
            docCounter++;
        }

    }   

}
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
at csvfilter.main(csvfilter.java:63)
```

Comment: Is `x.remove()` only being called once per outer loop? If in doubt then `break` after the remove.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Duplicates in the main list. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for [Iterator#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--)

> throws `IllegalStateException` - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method.

So it looks like `x.remove()` is being called twice before `next()` is being called.

Just make sure to `break` out of the inner loop after calling `x.remove()`.

Comment: In my case, your quoted text helped me that is "the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method." :D

Answer (score -1):

I usually initialize the Iterator outside the loop and use a while instead, never had that error pop.

Iterator itr = YOURLIST.iterator()

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
...
}